# Why CORS is blocked when using SocketIO with Express and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, cors

I am trying to develop a simple chat app using Node, React, Express & Socket.io.

Here is my Node server set up:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');
const socketio = require('socket.io');

// ENV VARS
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  require('dotenv').config();
}

const SERVER_PORT = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 5000;
const HOST = process.env.HOST || "http://localhost";

// INIT
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

// MIDDLEWARE
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('new client connected');
});

// ON LISTEN
server.listen(SERVER_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app listening at ${HOST}:${SERVER_PORT}`);
});
```

Here is my client side:

```
import {io} from "socket.io-client";
  
import './App.css';

const PORT = 5000
const HOST = "http://localhost"
const SERVER_URL = HOST + ':' + PORT
console.log(SERVER_URL);

function App() {
  let socket = io(SERVER_URL);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      aaaa
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I simply tried to test the on connection event, Yet I am getting the following error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NbN5Yrt' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

> polling-xhr.js:203 GET http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NbN5Yrt net::ERR_FAILED

i tried adding:

```
{origins: '*'}
```

as socket io doc says but the errors are still showing.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your reactjs app being served by the same express server you have at the top or is it being served from a different server?

Comment: What do you mean by different servers? All running on my local

Comment: When you run your react app with `npm start` you're starting a development server by default at `localhost:3000`. I think I should pre-emptively tell you when you build the production version of your app in the future using `npm run build` you'll need to serve those files somehow as you won't be able to use the dev server then.

Answer (score 1):

I think changing the order of initialization could help, because your `server` lacks all the middleware applied to `app`.

```
// INIT
const app = express();

// MIDDLEWARE
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.json());

// Create server and listen on PORT after adding middleware
const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app listening at ${HOST}:${SERVER_PORT}`)
});

// Try to avoid wilcard ('*') origins
const io = socketio(server, { cors: { origin: '*' } });

// Handle socketio connections
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('new client connected');
});

// EOF
```